# Interpreting sklearn's GP R^2

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, gaussian-process, cumulative-distribution-function

Sklearn can compute an $R^2$ value of sorts for a Gaussian Process regressor. As explained [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.score), the definition used is $1-u/v$, with $u$ ($v$) the residual (total) sum of squares. Since the result can be negative, it certainly doesn't have the usual Beta distribution of a linear regression's $R^2$, which is a shame because if it did I could convert the result to a CDF to see how impressive a high $R^2$ is. Is there any way I can interpret the GP's $R^2$, with a CDF or otherwise?

Comment: You can manually calculate R-squared (R2) as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)" to tell you how much of the dependent data variance is explained by the model. For example, if this calculation yields 0.95 the the model explains 95% of the dependent data variance. Using numpy arrays, which have a var() method to calculate variance, this would be "R2 = 1.0 - (abs_err.var() / dep_data.var())"

Comment: @JamesPhillips Getting $R^2$ isn't the problem; the problem is deciding how "good" the value is. Obviously one can't have an "ideally at least this number" rule, because such a cut-off depends on the dataset size. However, if I convert to a CDF, I can make a more reasonable interpretation.

Comment: If you have an R-squared value 0f 0.5 for a dataset with 5,000 points and an R-squared of 0.5 for a dataset with 100 points, in both cases the calculation I gave tells you that the model explains 50% of the dependent data variance. Because of this, I do not understand your reference to dataset size.

Comment: @JamesPhillips It's true that in both cases the same fraction of the variance is explained. But the amount that would be expected to admit such an explanation by random chance on the null hypothesis is size-dependent. Therefore, so is the significance level.